# OutofMemory Error while trying to deploy Drools Business-Central through Wildfly

Tags: drools, wildfly-8, rule-engine

I am getting this error while trying to deploy Drools Business Central using Wildfly.
The Error says:
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "jaeger.RemoteReporter-FlushTimer"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "pool-15-thread-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "MSC service thread 1-1"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "default Accept"

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

I tried increasing the memory allocation using the below code:
JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"

But this didn't work.

Comment: "this didn't work" isn't very useful as a problem report. What did happen? What does the memory usage look like in your VM? what troubleshooting have you attempted? (How did you choose those values in the JAVA_OPTS?)

Comment: What value did you change them to? Did you confirm they had taken effect by looking at the command line arguments to the process or using jconsole?